Why are my image dimensions smaller once they are published?
The title says it all.
I checked the image URLs and saw that each image has ?resize=768%2C559&ssl=1 (or similar) appended to it after the .jpg part.
Once I remove this, the image shows as normal.
I have modified the default image settings (Settings > Media) to make medium images 1024x1024 and large 2048x2048 but this hasn't made a difference.
This change has happened suddenly and isn't anything that I have (knowingly) implemented. My use of the site is the same as it has always been and I haven't modified anything with the theme or settings (aside from checking to see if default image sizes affected the images, but that was after the fact).
It is also affecting images historically (in posts that were published before this was a problem).
Any help, such as an explanation and/or solution, would be great.
Thank you.

resize= isn't standard WordPress, do you have any media related plugins or use a host with an image resizer such as wp.com? This may not be something that can be answered with just the information you've provided

No, I use IONOS and I don't use any media-related plugins (or if I do, I haven't tweaked anything to cause this change to occur). From what I can see, it does indeed look like something external to WordPress is adding in resize=.
